# How to Display or accept names instead of ids in Django Superadmin while using GenericFroeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I have a model for my project which is using GenricFroeignKeys for adding Stakeholders to Projects and Reposistories both.
The model is

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey, GenericRelation
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


class StakeHolder(models.Model):
    """Model class for Stakeholders of Project and Repos"""

    name = models.TextField()
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Role(models.Model):
    """This is the model for Role that the stakeholders will have o projects and repos"""
    name = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ProjectRepoStakeHolder(models.Model):
    """This is a generic models used to define stakeholders on project and repos"""

    stake_holder = models.ForeignKey(StakeHolder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    limit = models.Q(app_label='pr_reviews', model='repository') | \
            models.Q(app_label='pr_reviews', model='project')

    # Fields that are mandatory for generic relations
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to=limit,)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.stake_holder.name + "/" + self.role.name + "/" + self.content_object.name


class Project(models.Model):
    """Model class for Project"""

    name = models.TextField(unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Repository(models.Model):
    """Model class for Repository"""

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    name = models.TextField(unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(blank=False, null=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now if I have to add a Stakeholder to a Project or a Repository I have to do it by passing object_id (pk of Project or repo)

[Like in this Image. I have to pass object id of a repo or project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzZhq.png)

Is there a way I can add Stakeholders to a Project or Repo by using their names instead, without having to change the pks of project and repo? (Just like how superadmin handles adding FroeigKey relations by a dropdown). [Just like this (for ref)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CliOf.jpg)

Following is my admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from pr_reviews.models import Project, Repository, Role, ProjectRepoStakeHolder, StakeHolder


class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'is_active')


class RepoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'is_active', 'project')


class ProjectRepoStakeholderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('stake_holder', 'role', 'content_object', 'content_type')


admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)
admin.site.register(Repository, RepoAdmin)
admin.site.register(ProjectRepoStakeHolder, ProjectRepoStakeholderAdmin)
admin.site.register(Role)
admin.site.register(StakeHolder)
```

Please be polite if you want me to improve my question. I don't wanna get bullied like last time when I posted a question here. (just a newbie developer)